# Angular JS: How to get values in Cookies in different pages once it is set after login

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui

I am using Angular JS to develop a application. I want to maintain some useful data in cookies so that I can use it through whole application after user login. I have tried for $cookies and $cookieStore but not able to access the stored data in login to other pages, it is coming as undefined.

Can anyone please help me and let me know how I can access the cookies in different pages which set after login?

Thanks in advance.

-Sachin

Comment: It is hard to answer a question on a code issue without any code provided. Please share the specific snippet with us. Also, do you have included the ngCookies module? (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies)

Comment: Try using localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Why using cookies ? Do you need that data on backend ?

If you just need that data on frontend, why not using a service ?

Like this :

```js
angular.module('myApp').value('globalData', {data1:data1_value, data2:data2_value});
```

Services are singleton so you just have to inject your service when needed and clean it on logout.

Example on a controller :

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, globalData) {
    $scope.data1 = globalData.data1;
});
```